Termux : Asyncio error "asyncio.get_running_loop()" and "FileNotFoundError"
Hi and thank you in advance for your help,
I am currently trying to connect a tablet with Termux to a BLE Arduino. The code managed to connect my computer to the Arduino, but it doesn't work on my tablet for some reason and I can't figure out why because of my (very) limited knowledge on Termux, Bluetooth, Asyncio, as well as python packages.
The code uses Bleak and Asyncio to receive the Arduino data. Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to download Pybluez or Libbluetooth.
Here's the code I'm using :
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient, BleakScanner

# UUIDs
SERVICE_UUID = "fa33b723-c1a1-4886-b05f-252f8a0ba7b9"
CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "cc80869d-00c8-43a7-870e-8ea2f3b352a1"
DATA_FILE = "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/RelevésTH/data.txt"

async def handle_data(sender, data):
    data_str = data.decode().strip()
    try:
        with open(DATA_FILE, "a") as file:
            file.write(data_str + "\n")
        print(f"Data received and written to file: {data_str}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error writing data to file: {e}")

async def main():
    # Scan for devices
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    target_device = None
    for device in devices:
        print(f"Found device: {device.name} ({device.address})")
        if device.name == "NanoESP32_BLE":
            target_device = device
            break

    if not target_device:
        print("Target device not found.")
        return

    async with BleakClient(target_device.address) as client:
        print(f"Connected to {target_device.name}")

        await client.start_notify(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, handle_data)

        try:
            while True:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Stopping notification...")

        await client.stop_notify(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)

# Check if an event loop is already running
try:
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
except RuntimeError:
    asyncio.run(main())


And I obtain the following error :
~ $ python TabBLE2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/TabBLE2.py", line 47, in <module>
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: no running event loop

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/TabBLE2.py", line 50, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 654, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/TabBLE2.py", line 20, in main
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bleak/__init__.py", line 320, in discover
    async with cls(**kwargs) as scanner:
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bleak/__init__.py", line 158, in __aenter__
    await self._backend.start()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/scanner.py", line 168, in start
    manager = await get_global_bluez_manager()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/manager.py", line 1072, in get_global_bluez_manager
    await instance.async_init()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/manager.py", line 257, in async_init
    bus = MessageBus(bus_type=BusType.SYSTEM, auth=get_dbus_authenticator())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dbus_fast/aio/message_bus.py", line 200, in __init__
    super().__init__(bus_address, bus_type, ProxyObject, negotiate_unix_fd)
  File "src/dbus_fast/message_bus.py", line 169, in dbus_fast.message_bus.BaseMessageBus.__init__
  File "src/dbus_fast/message_bus.py", line 729, in dbus_fast.message_bus.BaseMessageBus._setup_socket
  File "src/dbus_fast/message_bus.py", line 702, in dbus_fast.message_bus.BaseMessageBus._setup_socket
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

dbus-fast, bleak, asyncio and others are already installed via Termux.
The code is supposed to return :
"Found device: NanoESP32_BLE (MACadress)
Connected to NanoESP32_BLE"
which it does on my computer.
Regarding the dir error, I tried putting the absolute path (as you can see), and write a few characters inside the data.txt file, but the error remained. So I have 2 errors that I do not know where they are coming from.
